# How can I use an AVPlayer with HTTPS and self-signed server certificates?

Tags: ios, objective-c, https, ssl-certificate, self-signed

I have a server that uses self-signed SSL certificates for HTTPS. I have the self-signed root cert bundled into my app. I'm able to get `NSURLSession` to use and validate the self-signed root cert by using `SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates()` in the `-URLSession:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:` delegate method.

When I try this with `AVPlayer`, however, I get an SSL error and playback fails. This is my `AVAssetResourceLoader` delegate implementation:

```
- (BOOL)resourceLoader:(AVAssetResourceLoader *)resourceLoader shouldWaitForResponseToAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqual:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]) {
        SecTrustRef trust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust;
        SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates(trust, (__bridge CFArrayRef)self.secTrustCertificates);

        SecTrustResultType trustResult = kSecTrustResultInvalid;
        OSStatus status = SecTrustEvaluate(trust, &trustResult);

        if (status == errSecSuccess && (trustResult == kSecTrustResultUnspecified || trustResult == kSecTrustResultProceed)) {
            [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:trust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
            return YES;
        } else {
            [challenge.sender cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

The delegate gets called, and the `trustResult` equates to `kSecTrustResultUnspecified` (which means "trusted, without explicit user override"), as expected. However, playback fails shortly after, with the following `AVPlayerItem.error`:

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x16c35720 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-1200 "(null)"}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.}

How can I get `AVPlayer` to accept the SSL handshake?

Answer (score 3):

This implementation has worked for me:

```
- (BOOL)resourceLoader:(AVAssetResourceLoader *)resourceLoader
shouldWaitForResponseToAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)authenticationChallenge
{
    //server trust
    NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace = authenticationChallenge.protectionSpace;
    if ([protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]) {
        [authenticationChallenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:authenticationChallenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:authenticationChallenge];
        [authenticationChallenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:authenticationChallenge];
    }
    else { // other type: username password, client trust...
    }
    return YES;
}
```

However, it **stopped working as of iOS 10.0.1** for a reason I have yet to discern.  So this may or may not be helpful to you.  Good luck!

Comment: I've since found that this was actually working fine on a device, but it would fail in weird and unpredictable ways _in the iOS simulator_, at least in iOS 9.3.x. I haven't tested on iOS 10 yet.

Comment: Same problem here, my implementation stopped to work with iOS 10, I did open an "Technical Support Incident" to try to solve this with some Apple engineer. If they manage to solve this issue I'll post the solution here.

Comment: Response to my TSI from Apple's engineer : It's probably a bug, I have to fill a radar for further investigation.

Comment: @Sylverb did you find the fix for this problem?

Comment: @UtsavDusad I've used one TSI, checked with an engineer, after giving me confirmation that it's not working, all he did propose is that I open a ticket with no garantee it will be solved one day ...

Comment: @Sylverb just tried this myself and still doesn't appear to be working. Did you ever hear anything?

Comment: @egfconnor I threw in the towel and used an AWS-issued cert, pinning the AmazonRootCA and letting AWS handle the management/renewal of the cert.  I highly recommend that route if it's an option for you.

Comment: Anyone fixed this issue?

Comment: @Sylverb in latest iOS 17.2/Xcode 15.1/Swift 5.9, I am not even getting the call to the method `shouldWaitForResponseToAuthenticationChallenge`. I get call to `shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource` after using custom URL scheme. There I fetch requested data with URLSession, that handles self signed certificate, and pass it to AVPlayer, it stays blank and does not play video. I will really appreciate your response. Thanks 